# QT 5.8 how does Webview do a request and how can I intercept it?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to pass QnetworkRequest to a  webView located in my main.qml file instead of a "url". I pass the url by referecing the webView object and the setproperty function. However, haven't found the right function and really do not know where to start in order to either create a new function or modify the existing webView code in order to get this to work.  Is there a way to edit the source code to the webView in the .qml file. Of course i am just learning the QT framework.

I have tried WebengineView but the Webview is MUCH faster in loading a page. and that is critical for the application

I guess the real question is how does Webview do a request and how can I intercept it?

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebView 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2


ApplicationWindow {


    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    visible: true
    x: 600   
    y: 400
    width:  500      
    height: 500 
    title: webView.title

    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "webView"

       //setting this value through main.cpp
       // url: "https://www.google.com"


        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.errorString)
                console.error(loadRequest.errorString);
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {

            QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
            QtWebView::initialize();

            QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

//How to Pass THIS request to the webview instead of url?
 QNetworkRequest request;

 request.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"));
 request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8,*;q=0.5");

            engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

            QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
            QObject *qmlObject = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("webView");




//Able to set the URL for the webView:
        qmlObject->setProperty("url", "https://www.google.com" );  

            return app.exec();
        }
```

Comment: How about handling of changed URL from QML when ```url``` property of ```WebView``` is changed? ```onUrlChanged: { ... }```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, all QML components use [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). You can register your own factory to have you own class handle the networking. You could overload the [get method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#get) and change the header if the url matches google, or whatever you want to do:

```
class MyNetworkManager : public QNetworkAccessManager {
public:
QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::get(const QNetworkRequest &request) {
    if (request.url.contains("google")) {
        request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8,*;q=0.5");
    }
    return QNetworkAccessManager::get(request)
}
}
```

Of course, here `request` is const so you would have to construct a new request, but I hope this shows the basic idea!

Example on how to register your own NetworkAccessManagerFactory in `main.cpp`:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-networkaccessmanagerfactory-example.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The rewritten methods are not called.
It seems that using the factory we can only get what is written in the documentation:
"By implementing a factory, it is possible to provide the QML engine with custom QNetworkAccessManager instances with specialized caching, proxy and cookies support."